# Trying to deploy Gatsby site to Netlify. Netlify can find some node_modules files

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a Gatsby site on Netlify.
I'm getting some "file or directory not found errors".

How do I resolve this?

Sample errors:

```
5:40:09 AM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/yurnalist-b654196c/examples/activity.js'
5:40:09 AM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/ssri-2b005273/package.json'
5:40:09 AM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/yurnalist-b654196c/examples/inspect.js'
5:40:09 AM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/ssri-2b005273/CHANGELOG.md'
5:40:09 AM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/yurnalist-b654196c/examples/list.js'
```

End of log:

```
5:40:11 AM: Error during NPM install
5:40:11 AM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
5:40:11 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
5:40:11 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
5:40:11 AM: Finished processing build request in 19.839635086s
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your implementation's specs?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it.

I was using FontAwesomePro and was lacking the `.npmrc` file.

Adding the `.npmrc` file fixed the errors.

Thanks everyone for their help.